# Remove all duplicate elements in a list

Tags: python

I have a list (ex: `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3]`) and I need to only keep the first occurrence of any of the elements in the list (ex: the list should become `[1, 2 ,3, 4]`). I know that I could do something like this:

```
badList = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3]
goodList = []
for element in badList:
    if element in goodList:
        continue
    goodList.append(element)
print (goodList)
```

However, this is a very messy solution, and I am hoping there is a more elegant way.

Comment: Do you care about the order of elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(badList))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

[credit to @poke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Answer (score 0):

Just convert to a set then back to a list:

```
goodList = list(set(badList))
```

Comment: This doesn't keep order which OP indicated he cared about

Comment: The order could be kept this way: `goodList = sorted(list(set(badList)))`